# angular-slickgrid filter not working.Filter is working if complete text is typed

Tags: angular, slickgrid

I am using angular-slickgrid.I want to enable filter.Below is the code:

```
prepareGrid() {
this.columnDefinitions = [
  {
    id: 'title', filterable: true, name: 'Title', field: 'title',
    width: 100, resizable: false
  },
  { id: 'duration', name: 'Duration (days)', field: 'duration', sortable: true, headerCssClass: 'grd-hdr' }
];

this.gridOptions = {
  enableAsyncPostRender: true,
  enableAutoResize: true,       // true by default
  enableCellNavigation: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableAutoSizeColumns: true,
  enableColumnReorder: false,
  enableGridMenu: false,
  forceFitColumns: true,
  rowHeight: 90,
  enableHeaderMenu: false,
  enableColumnPicker: false,
  editable: true,
  autoEdit: true,
  autoHeight: false
};
this.dataset = [{ id: 1, title: 'suresh', duration: 1, percentComplete: '10' }];}
```

On running application, filter is not working properly.See the screen shot:

**On running application, it shows one record, with title suresh:**

[image]

**Now if I type s in filter inputbox then it shows no record(It should show the record because there is one record with title suresh)**

[image]

I am unable to find the reason why filters are not working.

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug in Angular-Slickgrid library, which I am the author and that was fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/pull/351), the fixed was merged and a new version `2.14.3` was released.

Since this is a real library bug, it would be better to log this directly in the GitHub project instead of Stack Overflow.